# OpenApi authorize all services

Tags: java, spring-security, swagger, openapi

How can I add `Authorization` for all my Swagger services ? I have configure OpenApi and i have main Application with configured swagger, where other services are registred. In swagger-ui i have defined few services and I can choose one from list. For all my services I have configuration:

The "web" application it is main application where all of my services are registred and how can you see there are display as definition list in swagger.

What I'd like to achieve it is add Authorize and this lock for all my services from list for each endpoint.

Comment: Can you attach the OAS definition of your service?

Comment: I asked to attach the open api definition of your service in which you wanted to enable the security

Comment: Checkout this link - https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/, it has the format to enable the security globally for all resources

Answer (score 1):

On your code remove `MultipleOpenApiResource` which is already done by springdoc-openapi .

Use `OperationCustomizer`, by defining `SecurityRequirement` name to your different operations.

```
@Bean
public GroupedOpenApi usersGroup() {
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder().group("users")
            .addOperationCustomizer((operation, handlerMethod) -> {
                operation.addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList("basicScheme"));
                return operation;
            })
            .packagesToScan("org.springdoc.demo.app2")
            .build();
}
```

Note that you have complete working demo here which combines groups and `SecurityRequirement`:

- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-demos/tree/master/springdoc-openapi-spring-boot-2-webmvc

Comment: @mat373 for groups, you can filter by any criteria! packagesToScan is from the sample code. You can use combination with paths for inclusion/exclusion..